# Добавление плавности кнопкам веб-страницы(Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как странице добавить плавности при нажатии на бургер и стрелочку для разворачивания текста? Вот материалы страницы: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12j0DRb0sQD7hjQO5JBo4KNjCDEUXmAQs

Comment: Код можно тут вставить, на панели фрагмент кода html,css,js, картинка документа `<>`

Answer (score 0):

ховер эфект а там добавь transition 1s